# Trials, tribulations, and tributaries (Rainfall challenge)

Tags: ruby, community-challenge

This is a fairly simple Ruby solution to the [August 2016 community challenge](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6872/august-2016-community-challenge).

Ok, the title is way too dramatic. But [*tributary*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tributary) is a nice word, and the alliteration was too good to pass up.
<sub>Besides, konijn [started it](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/136752/14370)!</sub>

I didn't bother to output a 2D "map" of the basins, I just print their sizes as the challenge requires. (Printing a map wouldn't be a difficult thing graft onto this, but I just wanted to keep things clean.)

Anyway, the script:

```
# Simple class that models a point on the terrain
class Cell
  attr_reader :altitude

  # Init with the cell's altitude
  def initialize(altitude)
    @altitude = altitude
    @neighbors = []
  end

  # Add another cell instance as a neighbor of the receiver
  def add_neighbor(cell)
    @neighbors << cell
  end

  # Returns the "drain" of the receiver (lowest of lower neighbors),
  # or nil if no such neighbor exists
  def drain
    @drain ||= @neighbors
      .select { |neighbor| neighbor.altitude < altitude }
      .min_by(&:altitude)
  end

  # Returns the sink of the receiver, i.e. the drain's drain (ad fundum),
  # or self if the cell is itself a sink
  def sink
    @sink ||= drain.nil? ? self : drain.sink
  end
end

# Helper method. Given an array of cells, register adjacent
# cells as neighbors of each other
def link_cells(cells)
  cells.each_cons(2) do |a, b|
    a.add_neighbor(b)
    b.add_neighbor(a)
  end
end

# Get the terrain size (first line of input)
size = gets.chomp.to_i

# Init the altitude cells (as a 2D array) from input
terrain = size.times.map do
  gets.strip.split.map { |altitude| Cell.new(altitude.to_i) }
end

# Register neighbors (first row-wise, then column-wise)
terrain.each { |row| link_cells(row) }
terrain.transpose.each { |col| link_cells(col) }

# Divide into basins (cells sharing same sink) and print basin sizes
basins = terrain.flatten.group_by(&:sink).values
puts basins.map(&:size).sort.reverse.join(" ")
```

It passes the test cases given in the challenge. It also works with non-square terrains for that matter.

To my eyes, the code suffers a bit from the 2-step process needed to create a useful `Cell`. It's initialized with an altitude, but that isn't really useful until a 2nd pass links all cells to their neighbors. Just seems crude.
I considered having each cell know its coordinates and adding a `Terrain` class to handle the neighbor-lookups, but that seemed like overkill. And it'd introduce a pet peeve of mine: The circular referencing between a cell and the collection it's part of. I've run into this tons of times (e.g. board game-type code), and never found a solution that didn't irk me a little.

Anyway, there are probably more efficient solutions out there; I just went for simple and (hopefully) readable.

---

Looking at it again, I see a couple of issues related to the memoizing, but I'll wait and see what reviewers find.

Comment: I would really like to review something but wow it's nice! A really good example for me of how to write good ruby code!

Comment: @Marc-Andre thanks! But do wait and see if someone finds fault with it before you get too inspired ;) I'm sure there's stuff to improve

Comment: Indeed, but it still way more than what I do at the moment ! I'm still learning the standard library methods and everything else. It give some good ideas of how to use a lot of functions (even though someone could review and add more/better uses).

Comment: @Marc-Andre Glad to hear it! Speaking of using the stdlib, the advice I've given most often is to read through the docs for `Array` and `Enumerable` - repeatedly, till you go cross-eyed. There's a lot of really useful stuff there. I still catch myself about to write code that's built-in already. Second advice is to aim for a method length of ~5 lines if you can. At least personally, I find my code gets clearer with such constraints

Answer (score 2):

*I'm self-reviewing here, because I found some rough spots. Do **not** let this keep you, dear reader, from writing a review of your own!*

For this review I'll leave the overall approach as-is, and just focus on the details of its implementation. I'm nit-picking like crazy, but that's the fun part.

As mentioned in the question, I'm not super happy with the 2-step "initialization" needed to get a useful `Cell` instance. Mostly because it makes the `Cell` class tricky to use. Call `#drain` or `#sink` without adding any neighbors, and you get useless results. But at least you can add the neighbors later and try again. But call either method with *some but not all* neighbors added, it'll memoize possibly incorrect result. Adding neighbors after that won't correct the results.

One solution would be to wrap the `Cell` usage in an "outer" API. For instance a `Terrain` class or module, with a `#basin_sizes(input)` (or initializer) method that uses `Cell` internally to produce the answer. There'd still be a 2-step "initialization", but it'd be hidden from the outside world and (presumably) handled correctly.

Another (partial) solution would be to null the memoized results whenever a new neighbor is added. This way there wouldn't be the same risk of getting stale results, if, say, `#drain` was called before all the neighbors were added. It wouldn't solve the problem of `#sink` being memoized elsewhere, though: A cell's drain might change, but if other cells have already memoized a sink that relies on the cell's previous drain, they won't automatically update. Water doesn't flow uphill.

Speaking of memoizing, there's some inefficiency in the way it's used here. For a sink-cell, `#drain` will of course evaluate to `nil`. But memoizing a `nil` value with `||=` has no effect: Next time the method's called, it'll evaluate the right-hand expression all over again - and again and again, always producing `nil`. The point of memoizing should of course be that the right-hand expression *isn't* run again.

One way to solve this could be to use a 2nd instance variable to track whether the results been calculated yet:

```
def drain
  return @drain if @drain_found
  @drain_found = true
  @drain = ...
end
```

But that's not very elegant.

Alternatively, one could initialize the memoization variable to a separate value/type, like `false`, and check for that:

```
def drain
  return @drain if @drain != false
  @drain = ...
end
```

However, *all of this is actually academic*. Since the method that's actually called when solving is `#sink`, and memoization works well for `#sink` (no risk of a `nil` value). So in the end, the memoization of `#drain` doesn't actually matter: It's only called once anyway. In fact, `#drain` might as well be private.

But perhaps a better alternative overall would be to move the "lowest lower cell"-selection from `#drain` to `#add_neighbor`:

```
def add_neighbor(cell)
  reference = drain ? drain.altitude : altitude # get lowest altitude
  @drain = cell if cell.altitude < reference    # update drain if lower
end
```

*Edit: One could cut that down to*

```
@drain = cell if cell.altitude < (drain || self).altitude
```

*but it's probably clearer as-is.*

Obviously, `add_neighbor` might not be the best name for this method anymore. It's more like "set drain to this cell, maybe, if you feel like it"... yeah, I don't know exactly what the name should be. Maybe just `#register_neighbor` or something.

Anyway, it'd shift the drain identification to be "up front", and the `#drain` method could be replaced with an `attr_reader`.

Implementing the above yields a smaller `Cell` class, which is nice:

```
class Cell
  attr_reader :altitude, :drain

  def initialize(altitude)
    @altitude = altitude
  end

  def register_neighbor(cell)
    reference = drain ? drain.altitude : altitude
    @drain = cell if cell.altitude < reference
  end

  def sink
    @sink ||= drain ? drain.sink : self
  end
end
```

There's still the issue of `#sink` being memoized, so it shouldn't be called before all neighbors have been added/tested. As far as I can tell, this is a "lesser of two evils" question. Having the memoization there short-circuits the pathfinding, so the `cell#sink → cell#sink → cell#sink → ...` call stack doesn't have to go full-depth every time, which I feel is worth it. Again, the entire thing can be hidden behind a single API method to protect from premature memoization.

But I won't bother with that. The code's not intended for use outside of this script anyway, so for all intents and purposes the script itself is the wrapper.